# R calculate aggregate gains or loss using FIFO method

Tags: r

I have two datasets, one with details on stocks purchased called `buy` and the other with details on stocks sold called `sell`

```
buy = data.frame(TransactionID = c(1:10),
                 Ticker=c(rep('MSFT',4),rep('AMZN',3),rep('DOCU',3)),
                 Date=c(rep('01-01-2020',2),rep('01-14-2020',2),rep('01-01-2020',2),rep('01-14-2020',1),'01-01-2020','03-15-2020','04-06-2020'),
                 Price=c(100,102,102,107,2000,2010,2011,197,182,167),
                 Quantity=c(10,10,5,5,1,1,2,12,15,15))

sell = data.frame(TransactionID=c(1:7),
                  Ticker=c('MSFT','MSFT','AMZN','AMZN','DOCU','DOCU','DOCU'),
                  Date=c('01-07-2020','01-20-2020','01-01-2020','01-30-2020','01-15-2020','04-10-2020','04-20-2020'),
                  Price=c(97,110,2100,2050,210,205,225),
                  Quantity=c(7,12,1,3,10,5,3))
```

The `Date` is inputted in the format `mm-dd-YYYY`

My objective is to calculate the aggregate gain/loss on all transactions for the time period included in the data, using the FIFO (**First in First Out**) method.

I'm trying to do this programmatically using R but have not been successful yet.

**Method and desired output**

I attempted the calculation manually to demonstrate the FIFO calculation method and the final result that I reached. I have been looking for a way to do this using R, but have not found a successful method yet -

```
1) 01-07-2020 - Ticker= MSFT - Sold 7 @ $97 - Total = $679
                               FIFO Cost of 7 @ $100 - Total = $700
                               Gain/Loss = -$21

2) 01-01-2020 - Ticker=AMZN - Sold 1 @ $2100 - Total = $2100
                              FIFO Cost of 1 @ $2000 - Total = $2000
                              Gain/Loss = +$100

3) 01-15-2020 - Ticker=DOCU - Sold 10 @ $210 - Total = $2100
                              FIFO Cost of 10 @ $197 - Total = $1970
                              Gain/Loss = +$130

4) 01-20-2020 - Ticker=MSFT - Sold 12 @ $110 - Total = $1320
                              FIFO Cost of 12 @ $[3x$100 + 9x$102] - Total = $1218
                              Gain/Loss = +$102

5) 01-30-2020 - Ticker=AMZN - Sold 3 @ $2050 - Total = $6150
                              FIFO Cost of 3 @ $[1x$2010 + 2x$2011] - Total = $6032
                              Gain/Loss = +$118

6) 04-10-2020 - Ticker=DOCU - Sold 5 @ $205 - Total = $1025
                              FIFO Cost of 5 @ $[2x$197 + 3x$182] - Total = $940
                              Gain/Loss = +$85

7) 04-20-2020 - Ticker=DOCU - Sold 3 @ $225 - Total = $675
                              FIFO Cost of 3 @ $182 - Total = $546
                              Gain/Loss = +$129
```

**Output**

Total Loss:  -$21
, Total Gains: $664

Net gains are $643

Any help on how to reach this answer programmatically would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you calculating FIFO Cost? What's the formula?

Comment: The FIFO Cost of each stock can be found in the `buy` dataset.  As it is First in First Out, the price of the earliest stock purchase is considered first in the calculation of net gain/loss and then the later transactions are considered

Comment: Take for example the ticket MSFT. For point 1) listed above, the cost of the 7 shares are  $100 each as this was the price that the first 7 MSFT shares were purchased. For point 4) listed, the cost of the 12 shares of MSFT is split as 3 of the 12 shares are taken from the first batch of shares acquired for $100 each, and the remaining 9 shares are priced at $102 each, as they were purchased later for a higher price.

Comment: Hope that clarifies the calculation method

Comment: Ok I got the correct result. I will post my solution now, but I am a bit confused about the order of operations. Why is AMZN sale goes second, when it is the 3rd transaction in sell df?

Comment: @Varun, very good question.  You may have a look at my revised answer.

Comment: 1/2 Given that it's "tax season" in the US, I'm guessing more folks might be turning to this question and to the suggested solutions.  I'd caution any user who attempts to use code or programs below, however, as they are likely to be insufficient or wrong for anyone who has a more complex set of buying and selling during a given year.  For example, none of the solutions would be robust enough to incorporate into any brokerage or clearing house firm since the solutions offered only address the most simplistic scenarios/portfolios.  A complete and accurate solution would have to address (con't)

Comment: 2/2 additional complexities.  For example, none of the code offered seems to handle stock splits, corporate bankruptcies, mergers and acquisitions, and dividends.  So I'd suggest that anyone wanting to compute a cost basis for trades executed during a given tax year, obtain the cost basis from consolidated 1099's or 1099-B's that are distributed by the clearing firms or brokerage houses.  Otherwise, if you are going to "roll your own" solution, you'll need to account for the more complex situations I've described.  Just wanted to offer a word of caution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per comments, there may be non-integer `quantity` field in both tables.  In this scenario, before proceeding further, a minor tweak is suggested.  Let's say the quantity field can be rounded to 2 decimals.  Then in that case do this

```
buy$Quantity <- as.integer(round(buy$Quantity*100))
buy$Price <- buy$Price/100

sell$Price <- sell$Price/100
sell$Quantity <- as.integer(round(sell$Quantity * 100))
```

---

Needless to say, if your field is to rounded to three decimals replace `100` by `1000` in above codes.  But since the below mentioned approaches use `uncount` function from `tidyr` which will create as many rows as quantity is there, so it will multiply rows by further 10 times in this scenario.

Now proceed with either of these approaches.

Approach-1 (tidyr & dplyr) only

```
library(tidyverse)
buy %>% uncount(Quantity) %>%
  group_by(Ticker) %>%
  mutate(Price = cumsum(Price), 
         Quantity2 = row_number()) %>%
  right_join(sell %>%
               group_by(Ticker) %>%
               mutate(Quantity2 = cumsum(Quantity)), by = c('Ticker' = 'Ticker', 'Quantity2' = 'Quantity2')) %>% 
  mutate(CP = diff(c(0, Price.x))) %>%
  group_by(TransactionID.y) %>%
  summarise(CP = sum(CP),
            SP = sum(Price.y * Quantity),
            Profit = SP - CP)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  TransactionID.y    CP    SP Profit
            <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1               1   700   679    -21
2               2  1218  1320    102
3               3  2000  2100    100
4               4  6032  6150    118
5               5  1970  2100    130
6               6   940  1025     85
7               7   546   675    129
```

---

Approach-2 (using purrr::map_*)

```r
buy = data.frame(TransactionID = c(1:10),
                 Ticker=c(rep('MSFT',4),rep('AMZN',3),rep('DOCU',3)),
                 Date=c(rep('01-01-2020',2),rep('01-14-2020',2),rep('01-01-2020',2),rep('01-14-2020',1),'01-01-2020','03-15-2020','04-06-2020'),
                 Price=c(100,102,102,107,2000,2010,2011,197,182,167),
                 Quantity=c(10,10,5,5,1,1,2,12,15,15))

sell = data.frame(TransactionID=c(1:7),
                  Ticker=c('MSFT','MSFT','AMZN','AMZN','DOCU','DOCU','DOCU'),
                  Date=c('01-07-2020','01-20-2020','01-01-2020','01-30-2020','01-15-2020','04-10-2020','04-20-2020'),
                  Price=c(97,110,2100,2050,210,205,225),
                  Quantity=c(7,12,1,3,10,5,3))

library(tidyverse)
buy %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, '%m-%d-%Y'),
         buy_or_sell = 1) %>%
  bind_rows(sell %>%
              mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, '%m-%d-%Y'),
                     buy_or_sell = -1)) %>%
  split(.$Ticker) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>% uncount(Quantity) %>%
            group_by(buy_or_sell) %>%
            mutate(d = row_number()) %>%
            ungroup %>%
            arrange(d, -buy_or_sell) %>%
            mutate(profit = cumsum(buy_or_sell *-1 * Price),
                   d2 = rev(cumsum(rev(rev(cumsum(rev(buy_or_sell == -1))) == 1 & buy_or_sell == -1)))) %>% 
            group_by(d) %>%
            mutate(TransactionID = last(TransactionID)) %>%
            group_by(TransactionID) %>%
            summarise(Ticker = first(Ticker),
                      FIFO = sum(Price * (buy_or_sell == 1) * d2),
                      Sold = sum(Price * (buy_or_sell == -1) * d2), .groups = 'drop')
          ) %>%
  filter(FIFO != 0 | Sold != 0) %>%
  group_by(TransactionID) %>%
  mutate(Gain = Sold - FIFO) %>%
  summarise(across(FIFO:Gain, ~sum(.)))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>   TransactionID  FIFO  Sold  Gain
#>           <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1             1   700   679   -21
#> 2             2  1218  1320   102
#> 3             3  2000  2100   100
#> 4             4  6032  6150   118
#> 5             5  1970  2100   130
#> 6             6   940  1025    85
#> 7             7   546   675   129
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Well-done! Fantastic. I wish I could upvote again lol

Comment: I seem to be getting an error when I try both Approaches with a bigger dataset that is structured the same way `Error : Can't convert from weights <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
* Locations: 1, 2, 3`

Comment: @Varun, the error means that the quantity field in your buy data isn't of integer type. As uncount strategy has been used here and general logic says quantity should not be in fractions, try converting that field into integer first, and then proceed. Good luck

Comment: Would there be a way of allowing fractional quantities with your solution?

Comment: Hi AnilGoyal, any luck finding a way around the uncount strategy with fractional quantities?

Comment: Can I share the actual dataset with you via OneDrive? Sure, will upvote

Comment: Is there an email address I can share it to?

Comment: The desired output format would be the same as the one in your previous solutions, with the addition of the stock `Ticker`

Comment: I have shared it with you

Comment: @AnilGoyal could you please confirm if you've received it?

Comment: Sorry didn't see that. If it makes things easier, the decimal values can be rounded to 2 places.

Comment: That's fine @AnilGoyal

Comment: @Varun, check you mail.  I slightly tweaked this strategy (divided price by 100) and multiplied `Quantity` by 100 and converted it to integer.  Then run the same script to give you desired results.  Check and tell if it is correct, now

Comment: Your result is perfect. Thank you, I will give you best answer status as well if you can update your answer with the solution you shared with me.

Comment: I will modify.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

A bit messy, but works.

```
library(dplyr)

# First of all, let's convert date to Date class:
buy$Date <- as.Date(buy$Date, '%m-%d-%Y')
sell$Date <- as.Date(sell$Date, '%m-%d-%Y')

# Empty df that will have results of each transaction:
result <- data.frame()

# For each line in Sell df we are going to run this loop

for (i in 1:nrow(sell)) {
    
    print(sell[i, ])
    # Create a temporary table by filtering 'buy' df to the right Ticker and dates before or equal to Sell operation
    temp <- buy %>%
      filter(Date <= sell$Date[i],
             Ticker == sell$Ticker[i])
    
    j = 1
    sellQ = sell$Quantity[i]
    FIFO = 0
    
    # Running a while loop on temp table, iteratively updating FIFO
    while (sellQ > 0) {
      if (sellQ <= temp$Quantity[j]) {
        temp$Quantity[j] = temp$Quantity[j] - sellQ 
        FIFO = FIFO + (sellQ * temp$Price[j])
        sellQ = 0
      } else {
        FIFO = FIFO + (temp$Quantity[j] * temp$Price[j])
        sellQ = sellQ - temp$Quantity[j]
        temp$Quantity[j] = 0 
        j = j + 1
      }
    }
    
    SoldTotal <- sell$Price[i] * sell$Quantity[i]
    gain_loss <- SoldTotal - FIFO
    
    # Creating output line:
    output <- data.frame(round = i,
                         Ticker = sell$Ticker[i],
                         FIFO = FIFO,
                         SoldTotal = SoldTotal,
                         gain_loss = gain_loss)
    
    # Adding output line to result df:
    result <- rbind(result, output)
    
    # Updating buy table
    buy <- buy %>%
      filter(!TransactionID %in% temp$TransactionID) %>%
      bind_rows(temp) %>%
      arrange(TransactionID) %>%
      filter(Quantity != 0)
    
    print('Completed successfully')
}
```

Final output:

```
TotalGain = result %>%
  filter(gain_loss > 0) %>%
  summarise(totalGain = sum(gain_loss)) %>%
  .[[1]]

TotalLoss = result %>%
  filter(gain_loss < 0) %>%
  summarise(totalGain = sum(gain_loss)) %>%
  .[[1]]

NetGains = TotalGain + TotalLoss


print(paste('Total Gain:', TotalGain))
print(paste('Total Loss:', TotalLoss))
print(paste('Net Gains:', NetGains))

print('Details:')
result
```

Result:

```
> print(paste('Total Gain:', TotalGain))
[1] "Total Gain: 664"
> print(paste('Total Loss:', TotalLoss))
[1] "Total Loss: -21"
> print(paste('Net Gains:', NetGains))
[1] "Net Gains: 643"
> 
> print('Details:')
[1] "Details:"
> result
  round FIFO SoldTotal gain_loss
1     1  700       679       -21
2     2 1218      1320       102
3     3 2000      2100       100
4     4 6032      6150       118
5     5 1970      2100       130
6     6  940      1025        85
7     7  546       675       129
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems to be throwing an error when I try this with a slightly bigger dataset that is structured in the same manner. The error is `Error in if (salesQ <= temp$Quantity[j]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE / FALSE needed`

Comment: I have added try: except: in the loop, so if an error pops it should show you the transaction from sales where it took place and continues to next transaction. Maybe you can investigate. I assume there can be a problem where for some transaction there would not be enough stocks with Buy date before Sell date.

Comment: Thanks, the error now is `Error in try:temp <- buy %>% filter(Date <= sell$Date[i],  : 
  impossible to find the function ":<-"`

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad, used python syntax. I added now a print out of a Sell transaction at the beginning of the loop. If the loop finishes, it returns 'Completed successfully'. If not, you will see the line after which the error occurred.

Comment: Thank you! I think I found the missing one that was causing the issue. One last request please. In the `result` dataset, how would you include the `Ticker`?

Comment: Added a line when creating 'output' object (which is a single line that gets appended to result after each iteration). Please consider marking as 'solved' if this helped.